# Index Match like in excel but in R by two columns . Two Different Data Frames

Tags: r

```
   dput(df1)
structure(list(Op = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 
100), `Part No` = c("2352841G1", "2352841G1-500", "2352841G1-511", 
"2352841G1-512", "2352841G1-515", "2352841G1-516", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1-511", "2352841G1-512", "2352841G1-515"), median_Cum_Op.Only = c(0.000213043982232058, 
0.000105069443859436, 0.00296309606482585, 0.00391061342700764, 
0.000172384257117907, 0.000171817128581029, 0.000871527777225883, 
0.00368978009179786, 0.00420598379439778, 0.000299265043878997
), median_Cum_Total.Op.Plus.Queue = c(0.000213043982232058, 0.000105069443859436, 
0.00296309606482585, 0.00391061342700764, 0.000172384257117907, 
0.000171817128581029, 0.00299212962940887, 25.0171868055535, 
22.1245556712978, 53.9550010995374), median.op.only = structure(c(0.000213043982232058, 
0.000105069443859436, 0.00296309606482585, 0.00391061342700764, 
0.000172384257117907, 0.000171817128581029, 0.000618483793956262, 
0.000412083331633497, 0.000339699075729759, 0.000201851852514126
), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), groups = structure(list(Op = c(50, 100), .rows = structure(list(
    1:6, 7:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100016572", "100016572", 
"100049101", "100049101", "100049101", "100049101", "100049101", 
"100049101", "100049101"), Op = c(9997, 9997, 9997, 8391, 8392, 
8393, 8394, 8395, 8396, 8397), `Op Desc` = c("PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "MACHINE SHOP IAW 200365779", 
"ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200365779", 
"INSPECT IAW 200365779", "ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200365779"
), `Part No` = c("2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1"), WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
"G-CUST-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", 
"G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("26801702", 
"26801702", "26801702", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", 
"CHRI0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000"), `On Time Start` = structure(c(1557852668.803, 
1557852668.803, 1557852668.803, 1579215738.477, 1579279874.08, 
1579598294.2, 1579625528.097, 1579690071.267, 1583883648.167, 
1584029686.74), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    `On Time Comp` = structure(c(1585156034.313, 1585156034.313, 
    1585156034.313, 1579216621.723, 1579285486.47, 1579605490.21, 
    1579626040.097, 1583876924.857, 1584012522.213, 1584029801.71
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Span_CDay = structure(c(316.011174884259, 
    316.011174884259, 316.011174884259, 0.0102227546302257, 0.0649582175938068, 
    0.0832871527776674, 0.00592592592592593, 48.4589535879647, 
    1.49159775462967, 0.00133067129662743), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    Span.plus.Queue = c(0, 0, NA, 0.742310219906546, 3.68541805555699, 
    0.315207141201805, 0.747027430556439, 48.536769675927, 1.69026126157354, 
    1.77550760416521), Cum_Operation.Only_Span.in.CDays = c(316.011174884259, 
    632.022349768518, 948.033524652777, 0.0102227546302257, 0.0751809722240324, 
    0.1584681250017, 0.164394050927626, 48.6233476388924, 50.114945393522, 
    50.1162760648187), Cum_Total.OpPlusQueue_Span.in.Cdays = c(316.011174884259, 
    316.011174884259, 316.011174884259, 0.0102227546302257, 0.807268437500353, 
    4.5110154282412, 4.74886134259127, 53.9489164351865, 55.5183302777785, 
    55.718324456019)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    Order = c("100016572", "100049101"), `Part No` = c("2352841G1-516", 
    "2352841G1"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need in  df1  the data that is in df2 ,  only the last 4 columns in df2 will go to df1

It needs to be Match with Part Number and Operation.

Comment: Try `new <- df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% select(c(2,4,9:12)))` loading `dplyr`

Comment: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You have `tbl_df` but haven't loaded `dplyr`? Odd ... `library(dplyr)`

Comment: `library(dplyr)` and install it if not available as sir evans said!

Comment: FYI, your sample data here appears to have no matches (`any(df1$Op %in% df2$Op)` is false). I think @Duck should answer with the `dplyr` recommendation, and perhaps add base R: `merge(df1, df2[,c(2,4,9:12)], by = c("Op", "Part No"), all.x = TRUE)` as a non-`dplyr` alternative.

Comment: @r2evans You are right, data has no matches, so what to do in that case?

Comment: I think the answer(s) suggested so far should still be fine, and assume that the OP's data is what they think (and assert) that it is.

Comment: Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 10, 11, and 12 don't exist.
i There are only 9 columns.

Comment: yes, columns have different names Op = Operation

Comment: I need help, still does not work. I made name match and still does not work

Comment: Do you want `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Part No')` ? Obviously you can then keep only the columns that you want from `df3`.